# Google Chrome jumps to bottom of the page on <iframe>

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

I got such code at the end of the website for a pre-loader:

```
<iframe id="hidden_target" name="hidden_target" src="#" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
```

It works well on IE and FF, but jumps to the bottom of the page on load. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was register_globals issue. I needed to turn them on.

Answer (score 0):

maybe Chrome is trying to load the whole page IN the iframe, because when using the src '#' it refers to the current page

just a guess

Comment: No, page is loaded correctly, but it jumps to this <iframe> located at the bottom.

Comment: It was register_globals issue.